# Send data from Javascript to PHP using AJAX for updating the existing Mysql database

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, ajax

I am working on the backend of my snake game project.I have been trying to update Max entry of mysql database by sending the new highscore to update.php webpage using xmlhttp request through post request of ajax.

In order to test whether my data is sent to update.php,I have also sent the test=all good to update.php.But when I am echoing ,it is not displayed in the web browser thereby showing that no such data was successfully sent.

Please tell me why is it happening?

This is my code section of xml http request.

```
    '''
    highscore=score;
    document.querySelector("#my-high-score").textContent=highscore;
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.open("POST", "update.php", true);
    xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form- 
    urlencoded");
    xhttp.send(`highest_score=${highscore}&test="all good"`);
    '''
```

And this is the update.php file

```
    '''
    <?php
    session_start();
    $link=mysqli_connect("shareddb-x.hosting.stackcp.net","gameusers- 
    31353746432","havd5n897","gameusers- 
    3135374592");
    if(mysqli_connect_error())
    die ("connection is not successfull");
    echo "welcome user";
    $x=90;
    echo $x;
    echo $_POST['test'];
    if($_POST['highest_score'])
    {
    $high_score=$_POST['highest_score'];
    $email=$_SESSION['email'];
    if($_SESSION['highscore']<$high_score)
    {
    $query="UPDATE gameusers SET Max=$high_score WHERE Email= $email LIMIT 
    1";
    echo $high_score;
    mysqli_query($link,$query);
    echo "all fit";
    }
    }
    ?>
    '''
```

Please someone tell me where I am actually commiting the mistakes.

Comment: Start with checking your developers tools on the browser -> network tab. See if a request is being made. It's a useful tool to identicate requests issues.

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem? Is the request built properly such that the PHP script receives it properly? Also, be warned that your SQL query is widely open for SQL injection

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove to double quotes in "all good"

```
xhttp.send(`highest_score=${highscore}&test="all good"`);
```

Comment: Why? I want to store data of string type..Any thing written in double quotes is of string type

Comment: When you send request to a server via ajax post, it is not necessary to put the double quotes like you do.

https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_ajax_http_send.asp